# multiple select form in php

Tags: php, forms

I have the following in my HTML form, among with other inputs, like `<input type="test" name="foo"></input>` and others.

```
<select name="tags" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected" value="hello">hello</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="world">word</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that when I am using

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

the tags returned is a string, and it contains only the last item in the select, like this:

```
string(5) "world"
```

Any help?

Comment: the select should have name="tags[]" and the options should have a name each.

Comment: Have you tried `$_POST['tags']`?

Comment: @Graham, yes. I am using the var_dump there for debugging purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should indicate that it's submitting an array :

```
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
```

(note the `[]`)

Comment: fantasting, this is working :) give me 4 more minutes so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code. Name should be `name="tags[]"`. If you name is like name="tags" it will only pass one value, if you want to pass multiple values you should name it as an array.

```
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected" value="hello">hello</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="world">word</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option selected="selected" value="hello">hello</option>
   <option value="world">word</option>
</select>
```

And please don't use selected="selected" for every option. Selected="selected" should be used only for one option, the option to be shown default! This is very important!

Answer (score 0):

use `name="tags[]"` that way an array is passed

then you can use

```
if(isset($_POST['tags'])){
    foreach($_POST['tags'] AS $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

In this case be sure to set `method="post"` in your form tag.

You can use `selected="selected"` without a problem